# c++ read txt to string error

Tags: c++, string, text-files

This project is in c++. I am trying to move along a textfile, and print each time a substr of 80 characters long on the screen. The next step would be to update the start position of x and then print again. My goal is to 'slide' over a txt. When I start the second stream operation I don't get an error but there is no text outputted on the screen anymore.
Anyone who knows what i am doing wrong? Do i have to close the file before performing a new operation? Thanx

```
ifstream ifs("data.txt");
string line;
string subline;
int x=5;

while(getline(ifs,line)) {
    subline=line.substr(x,80);
    cout << subline;
}

system("pause");
system("cls");
x++;


//my issue!
while(getline(ifs,line)) {
    subline=line.substr(x,80);
    cout << subline;
}
```

Comment: You should really try to learn debugging your applications with your IDE/Debugger. What IDE are you using?

Comment: codeblocks.
and it doesn't mention any bugs.
For the record: i used 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

Comment: I don't mean compilation bugs. With a debugger, you can step through your application, examine its path, analyze variables, etc. Look at this URL: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code::Blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reaching the end of the file and it'll be setting the '[eof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/eof/)' state bit (and removing the '[good](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/good/)' state bit). That'll mean basically all subsequent read operations fail.

easy fix is to add after the x++:

```
ifs.clear(); // Get rid of the 'eof' state bit
ifs.seekg(0, ios_base::beg); // Go back to the beginning of the file
```

- [ifs.clear reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/clear/)
- [ifs.seekg reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/)

Comment: also I'd get into the habit of using ++x instead of x++ as it may be marginally faster; it doesn't need to make a copy of the object to return the old value before the increment.

Comment: Also @Fuzz is right above, you should probably be checking for ifs.fail() all along the way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you do need to close the file after using it. Always clean up every thing you do in programming, especially file operations.

Before actually doing any work on the file, you should check that the file did actually open successfully.
When you open the file the way you have (using the constructor) then you have nothing returned to you if the file open operation failed.

You can check the ifstream method 'good()' to see if the stream opened successfully, or 'fail()' to see if it didn't.

e.g.

```
ifstream ifs("data.txt");
if( ifs.fail() )
{
  std::cerr << "There was an error opening the file" << std::endl;
  return -1; // use -1, or some sort of non-zero number representing your error code to the command line
}

// Do your reading / writing

ifs.close();
```

I recommend reading [this info](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/) about some of the functions available to you when using ifstream.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to close the file before opening it the second time.
The issue is that the file pointer is pointing to last when the second read is performed.
Try resetting the file pointer to the beginning or reopening the file.